# Separate Grails logging configuration from Config.groovy?

Tags: grails, logging, configuration

Our Config.groovy is lengthy and we would like to begin to split key bits of configuration from the main file. Logging seems as good of a place as any to start for now.

**Is there a way under Grails 2.1.x to separate the logging configuration from the rest of the Config.groovy file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [external config](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) to separate configuration from `Config.groovy`